# Uncaught error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am getting this error:

```
ncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=ngRoute
```

This is the code that causes it:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Basic Angular</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Placeholder for views -->
    <div ng-view="">
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <script >
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

         myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider
                .when('/view1', {
                  templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
                  controller: 'SimpleController'
                })
                .when('/view2', {
                  templateUrl: 'views/view2.html',
                  controller: 'SimpleController'
                })
                .   otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/view1'
                });
         }]);

         var controllers = {}; 

         controllers.SimpleController = function( $scope ) {
            $scope.cars = [
                {brand:'Audi',  type:'SUV',         name:'Q5'},
                {brand:'Audi',  type:'Sedan',       name:'A7'},
                {brand:'Audi',  type:'Hatchback',   name:'Compact'},
                {brand:'BMW',   type:'SUV',         name:'X5'},
                {brand:'BMW',   type:'Sedan',       name:'X1'},
                {brand:'BMW',   type:'Hatchback',   name:'C3'}
            ];

            $scope.addCar = function () {
                $scope.cars.push(
                    {
                        brand : $scope.newCar.brand,
                        type : $scope.newCar.type,
                        name : $scope.newCar.name   
                    });
            };
        };

        myApp.controller(controllers);

    </script>
</body>
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by cdhowie is partially correct. After downloading the angular route libraries and linking it in the html, you need to inject it's dependency in the angular module. 
Something like this..

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[ngRoute]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message says, that service isn't available.  You didn't include the script that provides this service:

```
<script src="scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You need to download this script to your development environment if you don't already have it there.